# format amount column in jquery datatable as $ and thousand place as comma

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable and I have one column which is currently displaying amount with decimal.
I want to append $ in the beginning and put comma for thousand place.
Eg. Current its displaying as : 1526 or 1013.7

So It should display as $1,526 and $1,013.7

But most importantly it shouldn't break sorting functionality.

Code I am using is as below

first on page load :

```
var requestTable =
            $('#tblCustomerGrid')
            .DataTable({
                data: data,
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": 0,
                        "data": "clientId",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            $compile(nTd)($scope);
                        },
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            var hyperLink = "<a href='#'  ng-click='$event.preventDefault(); OpenClientInfo(" + data + ")'>Get Client Details</a>";
                            return hyperLink; //'<a href="Index/' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "type": "num", "targets": 5 }
                ],
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "clientId" },
                    { "data": "fullName" },
                    { "data": "email" },
                    { "data": "countryName" },
                    { "data": "phone" },
                    { "data": "grandTotal" }
                ],
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                    "thousands": ","
                }
            });

$('.panel-ctrls').append($('.dataTables_filter').addClass("pull-right")).find("label").addClass("panel-ctrls-center");
            $('.panel-ctrls').append("<i class='separator'></i>");
            $('.panel-ctrls').append($('.dataTables_length').addClass("pull-left")).find("label").addClass("panel-ctrls-center");

            $('.panel-footer').append($(".dataTable+.row"));
            $('.dataTables_paginate>ul.pagination').addClass("pull-right m-n");

            $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Search...");
```

then on button click :

```
 requestTable.clear();
        requestTable.draw();
        requestTable.rows.add(data);
        requestTable.draw();
```

As you can see I already tried

```
"language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                    "thousands": ","
                }
```

and providing type `{ "type": "num", "targets": 5 }` but none of them worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Datatables has a build inn function for this

```
   "columns": [
                { "data": "clientId" },
                { "data": "fullName" },
                { "data": "email" },
                { "data": "countryName" },
                { "data": "phone" },
                { "data": "grandTotal", 
                   render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' ) }
```

It also allows for more customization

https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers

Comment: Worked great for me using `columnDefs` . . . . `{
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$' ),
                "targets": 6
            },` . . . replace `6` with your target price column

Answer (score 3):

Here we can give format to multiple columns also

if want format like   decimal (.) and thousand separator (,) and currency sign like($) position before amount then follow following

```
var ib_dt = $('#ib_dt').DataTable( {

        "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false,
                  "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 2, '$','' ),
                  "targets":[3,4,5],
                }
            ],
});
```

if want format like   decimal (,) and thousand separator (.) and currency sign like(Fr) position after amount then follow following

```
 var ib_dt = $('#ib_dt').DataTable( {

          "columnDefs": [
                { "orderable": false,
                  "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 2, '','Fr' ),
                  "targets":[3,4,5],
                }
            ],
 });
```